# Direct url bar routing works while routerlinks fail - Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, router, angular-router, angular14

Running into an issue here with Angular 14 router. When I build out my routes as below. I can hit urls directly with it loading the correct components however if I use

- `[routerLink]="['specialUser/']"`
- `[routerLink]="['specialUser/coolList']"`
- `[routerLink]="['specialUser/coolList/neatPlace']"`

in my app it will change the url briefly, then strip the routerlink path off the url and then load no component at all. Except for the root ProfileComponet.

### app.component.html

```html
this is where the ProfileComponent loads
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

### profile.component.html

```html
simply a nested router outlet
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

### Routes

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LandingPageComponent },
  { path: 'privacy', component: PrivacyComponent },
  { path: 'privacy-policy', component: PrivacyComponent },
  { path: 'support', component: SupportComponent },

  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    children: [
      { path: ':username', component: ProfileDetailsComponent },
      { path: ':username/:listName', component: ListComponent },
      { path: ':username/:listName/:placeName', component: PlaceComponent },
      { path: ':username/fancy/:group/:fancy', component: FancyComponent },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Attempted pathmatch full in various places with no benefit after reading an extenstive instruction on how that works.

Comment: so those links are in profile component's html?

Comment: @PavelRodionov yup those router links live within the profile component itself. None of them are outside that component.

Comment: sorry, I am not so expirenced to understand how to fix it at a first glance.  Could you please reproduce it on a stackblitz so I could try to investigate?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is nest the child routes into each other and create new empty string paths to the root of each child.  Like so:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'profile',
        component: ProfileComponent,
        children: [
          { 
            path: ':username',
            children: [
              { path: '', component: ProfileDetailsComponent },
              { path: ':listName', children: [
                  { path: '', component: ListComponent },
                  { path: ':placeName', component: PlaceComponent } 
              ],
              { path: 'fancy/:group/:fancy', component: FancyComponent },
            ]
          }
        ],
      },
    ];
```